# Wordpress Metform Help Regarding Calculation of number field

Tags: calculation

I am making a form in metform plugin in wordpress. I am facing an issue with the calculation of the price.
https://desertsafaridubaihub.com/metform-form/evening-desert-safari-booking/
This is the booking form. The problem is I want to calculate the prices of these fields mention below when user want. if you user didn't want the price of these number fields do not add in the calculation field.
Actually I am using this formula to calculate the values."(adults) * 120 + (child) *120 + (single) * 150 + (double) * 250 + (sofa) *  70 + (camel) * 20 + (horse) * 20 + (shisha) * 70 + (falcon) * 20"
No. of Adults
No. of Child
Single seat quad bike
double seat quad bike
VIP Sofa Sitting
Long Camel Ride
Horse Riding
Shisha on table
Falcon pictutre

I just want to calculate the price of fields which user selected. Can anybody help me to sort out this problem?